# how to run `apt-get -f install'

Tags: linux, ubuntu

You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these.
 it says that everytime i try to download something and when i type it in the terminal it says

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
 could anyone help plz?

Answer (score 6):

[sudo](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudo.man.html) is your friend. It will allow you to run your command as root.

`sudo apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 1):

Some examples of popular uses for the apt-get utility:

Install a Package: Installation of packages using the apt-get tool is quite simple. For example, to install the network scanner nmap, type the following:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Remove a Package: Removal of a package or packages is also a straightforward and simple process. To remove the nmap package installed in the previous example, type the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove nmap
```